# Lodash: How to get unique values from an object array and then sort those objects by those unique values?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to use Lodash to grab unique values from an array of objects, then use those values as keys to sort the array of objects into. I was able to reach a solution, however I'm not sure it's the most sophisticated, readable or performance efficient way of doing this.

Using `_.uniq` and `_.map`, I was able to get the unique `country` values from each `artist`. I then looped through those values and filtered `artists` by them.

```
let artists = [
  { name: "Bob Jones", country: "Australia"},
  { name: "Jane Smith", country: "Australia"},
  { name: "James Good", country: "USA"},
  { name: "Jeremy Bond", country: "Japan"},
]

let countries = _.uniq(_.map(artists, 'country'))
// ["Australia", "USA", "Japan"]

let res = []

for (let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
  let country = countries[i]
  let obj = {
    country: country,
    artists: artists.filter(artist => artist.country === country)
  }

  res.push(obj)
}

console.log(res)
/* [
  { country: "Australia",
    artists: [
      { name: "Bob Jones", country: "Australia"},
      { name: "Jane Smith", country: "Australia"}
    ]
  },
  { country: "USA",
    artists: [
      { name: "James Good", country: "USA"}
    ]
  },
  { country: "Japan",
    artists: [
      { name: "Jeremy Bond", country: "Japan"}
    ]
  }
]
*/
```

Is there any Lodash feature I can use in place of the for loop and object assigning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy) to collect the artists to an object of `{ [country]: artists }`, and then use [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map) to transform the object to an array:

```js
const artists = [
  { name: "Bob Jones", country: "Australia"},
  { name: "Jane Smith", country: "Australia"},
  { name: "James Good", country: "USA"},
  { name: "Jeremy Bond", country: "Japan"},
]

const result = _.map(
  _.groupBy(artists, 'country'),
  (artists, country) => ({ country, artists })
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

And the same solution with [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) - using [`_.flow()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flow) to generate a function:

```js
const { flow, groupBy, map, head } = _

const byCountry = flow(
  groupBy('country'),
  map(artists => ({ country: head(artists).country, artists }))
)

const artists = [
  { name: "Bob Jones", country: "Australia"},
  { name: "Jane Smith", country: "Australia"},
  { name: "James Good", country: "USA"},
  { name: "Jeremy Bond", country: "Japan"},
]

const result = byCountry(artists)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Although I prefer the more succinct chained version: `_.chain(artists).groupBy('country').map((artists, country) => ({ country, artists })).value();`

Comment: I used to love chaining, but the problem is that you need to import the entire lodash package, and tree shaking can't reduce the size.

Comment: Now days, you can use lodash/fp with `_.flow()` to get a pipeline. See updated answer.

Comment: Very cool! I wonder what optimizations they do in the chained version over this one. I would imagine the majority of optimizations happen upon filter and so in this case both methods would perform nearly the same speed.

Comment: Chaining is lazy, so if you're using filter and map together, for example, it will only loop the array once. Flow is a convenient method to create a pipe of functions, so flow(filter, map) would iterate the array twice, and create an intermediate array. However, you'll only need to import flow, map, filter.